# CSS overlay by element as relative

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay

I am using twitter bootstrap and I want to create an overlay to show loading overlay. For example a **panel body** or a **well body** will fill and center a text "loading" or image.

I created a jsfiddle application here.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Body
            <div class="loading-overlay">Loading</div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="well">
    Well Body
    <div class="loading-overlay">Loading</div>
</div>

.loading-overlay{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
}
```

Bu overlay is filling all page. But I want it will fill only **well** element or **panel body**. or if I put it any other element.

sample [code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/0r7ytrk1/4/).

Comment: It's unclear, what you expect from your code? Just to overlay body tag?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is set the container element to a relative position.

In this case, since both .panel-body and the .well are supposed to contain the overlay all you have to do is add the following rules:

```
.panel-body {
    position: relative;
}

.well {
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3er5qjgt/

Answer (score 0):

That's because :

```
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;
```

Is transformed into : Take all the place possible on the page.

You could change the position to `relative`, or change the way you handle this.

Comment: I changed position as realtive and it sit on panel body but did not fill the body.

Answer (score 0):

Add class relative to parent container , to show loading overlay separate for each section.

```
.panel-body, .well{
    position:relative;
}
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0r7ytrk1/5/

Comment: But I should override all of elements position that I applied overlay.

Comment: Absolute position always works relative to the parent. If you don't override each element that you want to apply overlay, it will be relative to body and will apply to whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parents **relative**:

```
.well, .panel-body {
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0r7ytrk1/6/).